# FAcebook include php script instead of php output

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, share, output

I'm using Wordpress 3.8, and i have a page with insert php plugin.
The page works correctly, when it's called from the main site.
Inside the wordpress page there is written:

```
[insert_php]
require("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/podcast_manager.php");
[/insert_php]
```

But when I post the link on facebook, it outputs this:

[image: http://snag.gy/3MCb2.jpg]

Outputting php code, instead of running it!

Really I do not know why !

Comment: Is your PHP code in `<?php` tags? Does it have a file extension of `.php`?

Comment: my code is using wordpress INSERT PHP PLUGIN. It is a wordpress page.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the php code is in the body of the Wordpress post/page.  That creates a description (static text) that FB then reads, sort of like [Facebook Open Graph](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags).

To try to see if that is the problem, try creating a custom description by using a SEO plugin. Otherwise the PHP code is executing fine, it is just a description issue that FB reads from the header.

**EDIT**

View source of your post/page and see if the `<meta
name="description" content="">` holds that php string in it.

Comment: Ah - I thought he'd added the `[insert_php]` tags as markup on _here_. +1 for spotting that, and apologies to the OP for my overzealous editing.

Comment: yes i think that may be the problem. The code is in the meta description tag. Thanks i'm going to verify now.

Comment: modify description to a standard description removes the error, but actually, it's like the wordpress seo plugin is reading the page content, without running php. I think it is a conflict beetween wordpress seo plugin and insert php plugin.